# Can ggplot show regressions of y on x and x on y simultaneously?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I have a bivariate data set:

```
set.seed(45)
require(mvtnorm)
sigma <- matrix(c(3,2,2,3), ncol=2) 
df <- as.data.frame(rmvnorm(100, sigma=sigma))
names(df) <- c("u", "v")
```

Setting up `v` as the dependent variable, with `ggplot` I can easily show the "usual" least-squares regression of `v` on `u`:

```
require(ggplot2)
qplot(u, v, data=df) + geom_smooth(aes(u, v), method="lm", se=FALSE)
```

... but I'd also like to show the least-squares regression of `u` on `v` (at the same time).

This is how I naively tried to do it, by passing a different `aes` to `geom_smooth`:

```
last_plot() + geom_smooth(aes(v, u), method="lm", color="red", se=FALSE)
```

Of course, that doesn't quite work. The second `geom_smooth` shows the *inverse* of the proper line (I think). I'm expecting it to have a steeper slope than the first line.

Moreover, the confidence intervals are wrongly shaped. I don't particularly care about those, but I do think they might be a clue.

Am I asking for something that can't easily be done with `ggplot2`?

EDIT: Here is a bit more, showing the lines I expect:

```
# (1) Least-squares regression of v on u
mod <- lm(v ~ u, data=df)
v_intercept <- coef(mod)[1]
v_slope <- coef(mod)[2]
last_plot() + geom_abline(
    intercept = v_intercept, 
    slope = v_slope, 
    color = "blue", 
    linetype = 2
)

# (2) Least-squares regression of u on v
mod2 <- lm(u ~ v, data=df)
u_intercept <- coef(mod2)[1]
u_slope <- coef(mod2)[2]
# NOTE: we have to solve for the v-intercept and invert the slope
# because we're still in the original (u, v) coordinate frame
last_plot() + geom_abline(
    intercept = - u_intercept / u_slope, 
    slope = 1 / u_slope, 
    color = "red", 
    linetype = 2
)
```

[image]

Comment: I think you will have to write your own function to create the correct polygon representing the confidence interval and line for the fitted value as `geom_ribbon` is tied to the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(u,v), method='lm') + 
  geom_smooth(aes(v,u), method='lm', colour="red")
```

Comment: Unfortunately the second `geom_smooth` shows the *inverse* of the proper line. Generally it should have a steeper slope than the first line. And the confidence intervals are wrongly shaped (they're still in the vertical direction as can be seen at the ends).

Comment: Sure, makes sense now. I don't think that's achievable easily, but wait and see - I would guess it will require some extra work on your part!